# Trying to Merge multiple CSV files to one CSV file but get empty coma separated Values

Tags: powershell

So this is the following code in Powerschell that should merge all csv files to one

```
function getCVS{
    Get-ChildItem -R -Path ($PWD.Path + '\*.csv') | Move-Item -Destination ($PSScriptRoot + '\cvsData') -Force
}
$data = $null
function mergeCVS {
    $sourcefiles = Get-ChildItem -Path ($PSScriptRoot + '\cvsData')
    $result = @()
foreach ($file in $sourcefiles) {
    $data = Import-Csv $file.FullName
    $result += $data
}
$result | Export-Csv ($PSScriptRoot + '\cvsData\merged.csv') -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation -Force
}



#Search CVS Files
getCVS
#Merge CVS Files
mergeCVS
```

In the middle of the merged.csv file is a empty coma space.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzMmr.png)
Note: that there are Csv files with semicolon instead of comas.
My question is how can i filter the cvs so i dont have an empty space?
Is it possible to add the semicolon cvs with regex in the same merge.cvs?

Added delimiter for comas but it doesnt seem to work. Empty spaces are still a problem.

Comment: That is probably because the csv files have different headers.

Comment: Can you reduce your problem to, say, 2 files with only a couple of rows of data each that still reproduces the problem on a smaller scale, and then add the content of those files to your question.